# Kill a Specific set of process from shell script

Tags: linux, sh

I have a shell script that runs another java .jar which is running some automated tests with chromedriver.
sometimes it will leave 5 or 6 chrome browsers open when exiting.
*I'm currently working on fixing that but I need a tempory quick solution

I need a way to kill those process without affecting the chrome windows that didn't started by scripts

I tried the one below but it's only killing the first process

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do

openchrome=$(pgrep chrome)

java -jar uploadv2.jar

pgrep chrome | grep -v $openchrome |xargs -r  kill
```

Comment: Maybe you could get your java program's process ID (if it's java spawning the chromes) then use the `-P ppid` option on `pkill` to kill only the chromes where your program is the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this works but I think this is what it would look like based on Stephen P's comment. This assumes the java program only spawns chrome processes as children and no other processes.

```
#!/bin/bash

$openjava=""
while true
do 
    java -jar uploadv2.jar &
    $openjava="$openjava $!" # List of all java programs running
    # The $! gets the most recently spawned process id 

    for process in $openjava
    do 
        childProc="$childProc `pgrep -P $process`" #get chrome processes spawned by java
    done

    for tab in childProc 
    do
        kill $tab    #kill the child processes (chrome tabs) 
    done
done
```